How to Understand the Resisting Oracle for Feasibility Problem (Yurii Nesterov, Lectures on Convex Optimization)
I am struggling to understand Section 3.2.7 (Complexity Bounds in Finite Dimension) as whole in Yurii Nesterov's [Lectures on Convex Optimization]. I tried to search for similar results throughout the internet but it ends in vain, my hope goes here and I sincerely wish somebody can explain my questions about this particular section.

[Relationship between accuracy parameters] This comes from the very bottom lines on page 214: if we known an optimal value $f^*$ of the problem $\min_{x \in Q} f(x)$ (with $Q$ being closed and convex, $f$ being Lipschitz continuous and convex on $\mathbb{R}^n$), finding a $\epsilon$-optimal solution of it shall be amount to a (what-I-supposed-to-be) equivalent feasibility problem $$S = \{(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \;\vert\; t \geq f(x),\; t \leq f^* + \bar{\epsilon}\}.$$
Despite that Nesterov mentioned a relationship in terms of the Lipschitz continuity exists, I don't see any difference between the $\bar{\epsilon}$ and $\epsilon$ here.
[Understanding Resisting Oracle for Feasibility Problem] I find it very confusing that the resisting oracle on page 215 for the feasibility problem $$\text{Find } x^* \in S$$ has nothing to do with $S$, and it always find separators $g_m$ but never reports any $\bar{x} \in S$. What does the box ${B_k}$ generated means, why does its size matter with the lower complexity bound of the feasibility problem (as in proof of Theorem 3.2.7)?
[Theorem 3.2.8] I cannot find this theorem anywhere online, but I think that this is related to the relationship between accuracy parameters. From the look of Theorems 3.2.7 and 3.2.8, does $\bar{\epsilon} = 4\epsilon/M$ where $M$ is the Lipschitz constant?

Thanks for everyone's attention!
